# Azure custom translator size restriction

Tags: azure, microsoft-translator

Is there a size limitation on how many models I can build in a single project workspace. I see a size limit of 100GB for data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/custom-translator/faq

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no limit on the number of models allowed in a workspace.